# henselizations along closed subscheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Where can I find some references about henselizations ablong a closed subscheme?
For example if I take a map $Y\times\mathbb{A}^{1}\rightarrow Y$ and $Z$ a closed subscheme.

Let $Y_{Z}^{h}$ the henselizations along $Z$ and $(Y\times\mathbb{A}^{1})_{Z_{1}}^{h}$ the henselizations along $Z_{1}:=Z\times\mathbb{A}^{1}$.

What are the fibers of the map:

$(Y\times\mathbb{A}^{1})_{Z_{1}}^{h}\rightarrow Y_{Z}^{h}$?